# Apache slowly builds up processes and kills server

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, apache2

We have an Ubuntu server, running apache, PHP, and MySQL. Slowly over time, it seems the number of apache processes slowly increases (seen with ps -aef and top commands). Last night, it was so bad that the server was so slow it was unusable. I have no idea how all the processes were started, since we don't get that much traffic. There are many cron jobs running, but never more than 5-10 at a time. When I first start apache, I have the usual 10 processes, over a few hours it doubles, but this morning when I got in there were 100. I didn't run the top command with the 100 processes, but currently each one uses about 10M-40M.

I read about the prefork and worker MPMs, and wondering if changing settings may help. Currently using prefork with default values. Do I decrease MaxClients to kill the extra processes? Do I set a number for MaxRequestsPerChild so they're killed sooner?

Or something completely different?

Comment: is it fastcgi ? did you enabled ServerStatus or ServerInfo or ExtendedStatus to check how much of allocated resources are in use?

Comment: just enabled ServerStatus, we'll see if it helps

Comment: you should probably move this question to superuser.com or webmasters.stackexchange.com , good luck, g'night!